# Transfer textarea lines to arrays php

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I'm trying to use a form with textarea where I will put some emails.
After the form is submitted, `phpmailer.php` has to connect to smtp. Then for each line/email in textarea it sends an email.

Is there a way to do this without opening an smtp connection for each line/email?

This is the code in `phpmailer`:

```
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.example.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'user@example.com';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'secret';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    // Attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can explode emails posted by form and add each of them as Bcc like:

```
$_POST['emails'] = 
    'email1@example.com
    email2@example.com
    email3@example.com
    email4@example.com
    email5@example.com';

$emails=explode(PHP_EOL, $_POST['emails']);
   
foreach ($emails as $email) {
    $mail->addBCC($email);
}
```

[test PHP code online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=71dc62156e05b76b57ff8622fa8a313f&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: is there a way without BCC just normail email?

Comment: Using BCC is common way to send same email message to different receivers without show list of receivers  to  each of them. It is the way to send multiple emails using single SMPT session.